# Create a Point property from coordinates in string format from a csv column in Neo4j/Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, point

I'm trying to build a graph from a csv files containing the following columns  :

```
Name,coordinates
name1, "latitudeValue,longitudeValue"
```

(with latitudeValue and longitudeValue corresponding to latitude and longitude values)

As you can see, the two values are in a string format, separated by a comma. I'm trying to create a Point format property using the coordinates. However, I can't figure out the correct method to split the string (for a given line) by the comma and assign the longitude and the latitude to Point's parameter.

Here is my what my code currently looks like :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:Node{id:linenumber(),name:coalesce(line.`name`,"Unkown")})
    WITH n, split(line.`coordinates`, ",") as coordinates
    SET n.coord=Point({longitude:toFloat(coordinates[1]),latitude:toFloat(coordinates[0])})
```

The code returns no error but doesn't seem to create the coord property.

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't create the point property?

Answer (score 0):

There are a two typo errors on your csv file. Column name "Name" should be "name" (neo4j is case sensitive) then also the csv file includes the space in "coordinates" so it is returning incorrect value.

```
OLD csv:
Name,coordinates
name1, "10,20"

CORRECTED csv: 
name,coordinates
name1,"10,20"
```

Sample result after correcting your csv file:

[image]